# JS Function to create link - how?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in my html

```
<input type="image" src=images/more.png   onClick="showInviteInfo() />
```

When clicked it brings up a pop up box via this js function.

```
function showInviteInfo(){
        document.getElementById("divsignup").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("txtemail").focus();

}
```

But I no longer want it to bring up pop up rather when clicked take user to a new page.   What do I need to change?  Probably easy, but I am a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
window.location = "new location path";
```

in your function.

[window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

If you can use  an anchor tag then it would be like this.

```
<a href="new location" id="anchLoc">Click here to navigate to new page</a>
```

Comment: thanks function { window.location = "   " }

worked great in Firefox at least.

cheers & thnx again

Comment: it would need to be function NAME() {window.location = "";}

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<input type="image" src=images/more.png   onClick="showInviteInfo() />
```

to

```
<a href="YOURLINK"><img src="images/more.png" /></a>
```

EDIT: sorry, the editor was giving me grief with the second line

Comment: this is assuming I understood the OP correctly (as opposed to the title) - you have a button that shows a popup but you want to change it to just navigate to the new page? No javascript required...